# Methods lacking return types and no void?

Tags: java, methods, return, void

This piece of code is in my textbook, but what I'm not understanding is the method TestPanels(). It has no return type AND no void. How can this happen?

```
public class TestPanels extends JFrame {

public TestPanels() { 
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        p1.add(new JButton(""+i));
    }

    p1.add(new JButton(""+0));
    p1.add(new JButton("Start"));
    p1.add(new JButton("Stop"));

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p2.add(new JTextField("Time to be displayed here"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(p2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(new JButton("Food to be placed here"), BorderLayout.WEST); 

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestPanels frame = new TestPanels();
    frame.setTitle("The Front View of a Microwave Oven");
    frame.setSize(400, 250);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
}
```

Comment: It's a constructor. Look up "constructor" in the index of your book and start reading from there.

Comment: Thats a constructor, Constructors create an object. They don't return anything in a way it returns the object.

Comment: Buy a better book on Java. Before going to a book on UI stuff. This will covered in Chapter 1. Even in the really bad books.

Comment: You should read this article http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Its a constructor and not a method. Please check the documentation here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Please provide some reference in order to enrich your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a constructor and not a method. Methods will always have return-type or void (no return value).

Answer (score 0):

That is not a `Method` (which is a function attached to a class), but rather a `Constructor`. `Constructors` are used to instantiate or "create" objects/classes.

These resources should help you farther understand them:

Constructor: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html

Method: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's a constructor for the object `TestPanels`. Calling it in a statement such as `TestPanels t = new TestPanels()` would create an object with 9 `JButton`s, and all the other components created in `TestPanels()`.

It's basically a way to initiate the attributes of an object, same way as `JButton b = new JButton("Button")` would give you a button that says "Button".